# How to pass compiler arguments to java Compiler with kotlin dsl Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to add arguments `--add-exports java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED` to java compiler for my gradle build task. I'm using gradle kotlin dsl.

Below is the updated JavaCompiler task.

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    val compilerArgs = options.compilerArgs
    compilerArgs.add("--add-exports java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED ")
}
```

When I run `gradle compileJava` task I get below error.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>
> > error: invalid flag: --add-exports java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED
>
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/CompileOptions.html#getCompilerArgs--), `options.compilerArgs` returns `List<String>`. So you can write like this instead:

```gradle
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    val compilerArgs = options.compilerArgs
    compilerArgs.addAll(listOf("--add-exports", "java.rmi/sun.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED"))
}
```

Also make sure you have Java 9+.